# How can I limit the objects from a group in a query in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have this query in my code which allows me to build a tag cloud for this blog front page

```
tagCloud:allContentfulBlogPost {
  group(field: tags, limit: 8) {
     fieldValue
  }
}
```

It's passing data that I map in my component using `{data.tagCloud.group.map(tag => (...))};`. The code works nicely, but it won't be limited by the filter I'm passing above in the `group(fields: tags, limit: 8)` in my query. It renders all the tags and not only the first eight.

I've unsuccessfully tried the skip filter as well for the sake of seeing if it works.
Is this the proper way to limit the count to my mapping component in Gatsby?

Answer (score 0):

The Contentful source plugin doesn't define arguments on any of the nodes it creates, unfortunately. Instead you would need to create these yourself. The easiest way to do that is through the [`createResolvers` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/#createResolvers).

Here's a similar example from a project of mine:

```
// in gatsby-node.js
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
  createResolvers({
    SourceArticleCollection: {
      // Add articles from the selected section(s)
      articles: {
        type: ["SourceArticle"],
        args: {
          // here's where the `limit` argument is added
          limit: {
            type: "Int",
          },
        },
        resolve: async (source, args, context, info) => {
          // this function just needs to return the data for the field;
          // in this case, I'm able to fetch a list of the top-level
          // entries that match a particular condition, but in your case
          // you might want to instead use the existing data in your
          // `source` and just slice it in JS.
          const articles = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
            query: {
              filter: {
                category: {
                  section: {
                    id: {
                      in: source.sections.map((s) => s._ref),
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            type: "SourceArticle",
          })

          return (articles || []).slice(0, args.limit || source.limit || 20)
        },
      },
    },
  })
}
```

Because resolvers run as part of the data-fetching routines that support the GraphQL API, this will run server-side at build-time and only the truncated/prepared data will be sent down to the client at request time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not that experienced so to make sure I'm not misunderstanding, this will use the createResolvers API to define those arguments. So, in `types: ['SourceArticle']` I will define my node `contentfulBlogPost`?  I'm not sure that I understand how this will affect only a specific query like that. And about the last function `resolve: async() => {  }`, that would limit all the posts? I've queries in another places in my project that use the "whole" query { allContentfulBlogPost { group(fields: tags) for render.

Comment: The `type` field defines the GraphQL type that is expected as a response. In the example above, it's an array of `SourceArticle` types. If you want to extend `ContentfulBlogPost`, you'd use it in place of `SourceArticleCollection` (the key to the object being passed to `createResolvers`). The `resolve` parameter is the function that does the work of retrieving the records associated with the field. The quantity limiting is happening on the last line (paraphrasing: `return [].slice(0, args.limit)`).

Comment: Perhaps I'm getting this all wrong. Did some changes and got this in return on build: "7:26:28 PM: warning `createResolvers` passed resolvers for type `allContentfulBlogPost` that doesn't exist in the schema. Use `createTypes` to add the type before adding resolvers." But that's ok, I've solved the issue setting a height and hid all overflow with css. Thanks!

Comment: `allContentfulBlogPost` is a field name on the root `Query` type. You need to specify the *type*, which in this case is going to be `ContentfulBlogPost` as I mentioned above.